# Session aborts when debugging a function

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

I have a toy function, `foo`, that just adds 5 to a variable `x`. I have a second function, `n_foo` that applies `foo` to a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) `n` times. It works like so:

```r
# Load library
library(data.table)

# Dummy function
foo <- function(x){
  x + 5
}

# Apply foo n times
n_foo <- function(x, n){
  Reduce(function(a, b) foo(a), 1:n, init = x)
}

# Dummy data
dt <- data.table(values = 1:10)

# Run foo 5 times
dt[, test := n_foo(.SD, 5)]

# See results
dt
#>     values test
#>  1:      1   26
#>  2:      2   27
#>  3:      3   28
#>  4:      4   29
#>  5:      5   30
#>  6:      6   31
#>  7:      7   32
#>  8:      8   33
#>  9:      9   34
#> 10:     10   35
```

Great! Now, say something was amiss and I wanted to debug `n_foo`, I'd pull out the trusty `debug` function.

## WARNING: THE FOLLOWING CODE MIGHT CRASH YOUR SESSION.

```r
# Load library
library(data.table)

# Dummy function
foo <- function(x){
  x + 5
}

# Apply foo n times
n_foo <- function(x, n){
  Reduce(function(a, b) foo(a), 1:n, init = x)
}

# Dummy data
dt <- data.table(values = 1:10)

debug(n_foo)

# Run foo 5 times
dt[, test := n_foo(.SD, 5)]

# See results
dt
```

produces,

[image]

Curiously, the session *doesn't* crash if this code is run using `reprex`. Why does this code lead to a fatal error?

---

## Edit:

It turns out I can only produce this issue in RStudio and *not* at the CLI. RStudio tag added accordingly.

---

```r
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.8

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.0 tools_4.0.0
```

Comment: Can you please try to reproduce this on the command line (not RStudio) -- the command line gives more helpful debugging info in the event of a crash [e.g. what type of crash, and something like a call stack in C]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MichaelChirico – no issues when running at the CLI. I guess it must be an RStudio issue.

Comment: I'm not getting this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to RStudio v. 1.3.959, I could no longer reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

no crash... but goes into debugging...

```
debugging in: n_foo(.SD, 5)
debug at #1: {
    Reduce(function(a, b) foo(a), 1:n, init = x)
}
Browse[2]>
```

info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.12.8

rstudio 1.3.959
```

Comment: Thanks for testing it, Wimpel – it's much appreciated. That's what I get in `reprex`. So strange. I might delete this question if it's just a problem on my machine...